# A polynomial of nth degree that is irreducable in a finite field of characteristic 2

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I know there are algorithms to factor polynomials over finite fields, outlined on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Factoring_algorithms). I have also found [a paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1071579714000586) which gives the number of irreducible polynomials of $n$th degree in a finite field of characteristic 2.
I am looking for some form of a polynomial of degree $n$ that is irreducible in GF(2) for any $n$. I have briefly considered $x^n+x+1$, but there is a counterexample $x^5+x+1 = (x^2 + x + 1) (x^3 + x^2 + 1)$. I apologize if this is a trivial or well-known result since I have a very poor background in number theory.

Comment: While _counting_ them is well-known, identifying specific ones in a formulaic (as opposed to merely algorithmic) way for all $n$ is not "well-known to _me_". :) But more-expert people may know some recent development that are at least semi-formulaic, or anyway more qualitative than any of the obvious more-or-less-efficient algorithms.

Comment: Related: [General way to find monic irreducible polynomial of degree $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3426588/general-way-to-find-monic-irreducible-polynomial-of-degree-n) and [Algorithm to find the irreducible polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654562/algorithm-to-find-the-irreducible-polynomial) and [Product of all monic irreducibles with degree dividing $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106721/product-of-all-monic-irreducibles-with-degree-dividing-n-in-mathbbf-q)

Comment: For the record, $x^n + x + 1$ is reducible in $\mathbf Z[x]$ (and thus in $\mathbf F_2[x]$) if $n \equiv 2 \bmod 3$ and $n > 2$: $n = 5, 8, 11, 14, \ldots$.  These polynomials always have $x^2+x+1$ as a factor. See Example 5 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ringtheory/irredselmerpoly.pdf.

Comment: For no prime $p$ is there a simple explicit recipe for an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbf F_p[x]$ for *every* $n$.